# I'm using VMWare Player to run Ubuntu 14.04 on a Windows 8 Host and the 3d acceleration checkbox for the VM is disabled

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, vmware-player

Ubuntu 14.04 is usable, but noticeably slower in the Unity interface, apparently due to lack of hardware 3d acceleration, and I see in the VM settings that there is a checkbox to enable hardware 3d acceleration, but I can't check the box (it's disabled).  Is there some way I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

OOOooooh, If I shutdown the virtual machine (not just suspend it), then it allows me to edit the display settings.

Well, that answers that. :)